# Why does “jump” have “up and down”?

Tags: word-usage

to push yourself suddenly off the ground and into the air using your legs:

The children were jumping up and down with excitement.

It means “raise oneself up,” but how can “down” be added?

Comment: They're not "jumping down". They're ***jumping***, which causes them to ***move*** up and down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be exact, the children are jumping up and falling down. If you jump **up**, using your legs, you will ascend a small distance only, not even one metre, and after reaching that height, gravity will claim you and you will fall **down** again to the ground. When your feet touch the ground, you can jump again. You can repeat this cycle until you feel tired or wish to stop.  Overall, you are seen to move **up and down**, and that is how we describe the action.